# Python : Selenium click account creation

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have to automate account creation for few "Senior Citizen" that live in nursing home. (for free, I'm volunteer)
I'm figuring out how to click on button like this :

```
<button type="submit" data-uid="id-3" role="button" class="_2CEO5 _2eWEL _3cHWt _2Jtx4 V9Kxm _1s9tX _2eWEL _3cHWt _2eWEL _3cHWt _2Jtx4 _3cHWt _5Qrl3">
<span class="_100nC"><div class="_2EteE _2WXqV _34xiU _1TcN5 _2WXqV _34xiU" style="border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div></span><span class="_2HwQ3">Create an Account</span></button>
```

I tried with
on chrome browser , righ-click > copy Xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plex"]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/button')
```

but the Selenium cant find it

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="plex"]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/button"}
```

How to click ?
Thank for any hints

The url is: https://www.plex.tv/sign-up/

Comment: Share the website so people can help you.

Comment: unfortunately not works , a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div._2JCNt>form>button") Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div._2JCNt>form>button"}

Comment: Since the site is an iframe, I think you can directly get the iframe link and go there and directly reach the button. (iframe id = fedauth-iFrame) You Find. You can go directly from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating directly to their login auth iframe link

```
from selenium import webdriver


  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.plex.tv/sign-up/')

#accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[3]/a[2]').click()
#navigate to iframe src
driver.get(driver.find_element_by_id("fedauth-iFrame").get_attribute('src'))
#input email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys("email@email.com")
#input password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('password')
#submit
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plex"]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/button/span[2]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.plex.tv/sign-up/")
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/a[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/a").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[5]/a").click()
except Exception as e:
    print("Nothing to click before submission!")

iframe_el = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fedauth-iFrame")
# iframe_el.get_attribute("src")


try:
    driver.get(iframe_el.get_attribute("src"))
    # fill the form
    element = (
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/button")
            )
        )
        .click()
    )
    print("button is found")

except Exception as e:
    print("no element")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targetting the parent *BUTTON* target the inner *SPAN* inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit'][data-uid^='id'] span:nth-of-type(2)"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit' and starts-with(@data-uid, 'id')]//span[text()='Create an Account']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)